# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, None, None, 1) vs (None, None))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-processing, deep-learning

I'm currently learning about deep learning & I was working on a image classification problem while following a blog & few articles.
There is a problem occurring with the shapes and dimensions of the model I'm trying to create. The model I want is combination of ResNet & UNet. This is the very initial code I was working with.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import cv2
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, UpSampling2D, Concatenate, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# Load data
data_path = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Allergy Data/train'
train_data = []
val_data = []

for folder in os.listdir(data_path):
    folder_path = os.path.join(data_path, folder)
    file = os.listdir(folder_path)
    num_train = int(0.8 * len(file))
    files_train = random.sample(file, num_train)
    files_val = list(set(file) - set(files_train))

    for file in files_train:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        img = cv2.imread(file_path)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
        train_data.append((img, folder))

    for file in files_val:
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        img = cv2.imread(file_path)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
        val_data.append((img, folder))

# Visualize data
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(15, 10))
plt.suptitle('LABELS OF EACH IMAGE')

for (img, label), ax in zip(random.sample(train_data, 8), axes.flatten()):
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_title(label)
    ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

plt.show()

# Preprocess data
X_train, y_train = zip(*train_data)
X_val, y_val = zip(*val_data)

# Encode labels
le = LabelEncoder()
y_train_encoded = le.fit_transform(y_train)
y_val_encoded = le.transform(y_val)

# One-hot encode labels
num_classes = len(np.unique(y_train_encoded))
y_train_one_hot = to_categorical(y_train_encoded, num_classes)
y_val_one_hot = to_categorical(y_val_encoded, num_classes)

# Build ResNet50 model
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
base_model.trainable = False

# Build UNet segmentation head
def build_unet(input_tensor, encoder_output_size):
    upsampled_input = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(input_tensor)
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([upsampled_input, encoder_output_size])
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, encoder_output_size])
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, encoder_output_size])
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, encoder_output_size])
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, encoder_output_size])
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, encoder_output_size])
    x = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(x)  # Output mask
    return x

# Connect ResNet and UNet
resnet_output = base_model.output
unet_output = build_unet(resnet_output, base_model.get_layer('conv4_block6_out').output)

# Build combined model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=unet_output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Data augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = datagen.flow(np.array(X_train), y_train_one_hot, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)
val_generator = datagen.flow(np.array(X_val), y_val_one_hot, batch_size=8, shuffle=False)

# Train the model
EPOCHS = 10
history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, epochs=EPOCHS,
                    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train)//8, validation_steps=len(X_val)//8)

# Save the model
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/Allergy Data/my_model.h5')

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Allergy Data/test'
real_label = []
predicted_class = []

for folder in os.listdir(test_path):
    folder_path = os.path.join(test_path, folder)
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        img = cv2.imread(file_path)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
        img = preprocess_input(np.array([img]))
        predictions = model.predict(img)
        real_label.append(folder)
        predicted_class_index = np.argmax(predictions)
        predicted_class.append(le.classes_[predicted_class_index])

# Confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(real_label, predicted_class)
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues')
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Actual')
plt.show()
```

I have tried using alternate codes, and alternate values as arguments but It's still not working.

```
#before
train_generator = datagen.flow(np.array(X_train), y_train_one_hot, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
val_generator = datagen.flow(np.array(X_val), y_val_one_hot, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)

#after
train_generator = datagen.flow(np.array(X_train), y_train_one_hot, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
train_generator = ((images, masks) for (images, labels) in train_generator)

val_generator = datagen.flow(np.array(X_val), y_val_one_hot, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)
val_generator = ((images, masks) for (images, labels) in val_generator)
```

I also tried:

```
#before
y_train_one_hot = to_categorical(y_train_encoded, len(le.classes_))
y_val_one_hot = to_categorical(y_val_encoded, len(le.classes_))

#after
y_train_one_hot = y_train_one_hot.reshape((len(y_train_one_hot), 14, 14, 1))
y_val_one_hot = y_val_one_hot.reshape((len(y_val_one_hot), 14, 14, 1))
```